# Decorating JOptionPane.showMessageDialog, like make borderless

Tags: java, swing

Is is possible to create border-less message box in java swing or decorate it further?

Comment: It's fairly open as to what you can put in a container and display in a `JOptionPane`, but usually it is easier to create a `JDialog` to the exact requirement, than it is to 'tweak' an option pane to need.

Comment: What is for you borderless? Without border and title bar (`Dialog.setUndecorated(true)`)? Only without border?

Comment: @Sergiy yes, I need a message box without border and title bar and I am using  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(). Is it possible to achieve using it or do I need to look for some other better alternatives. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use global listeners to implement required functionality. here is an example

```
import java.awt.AWTEvent;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.AWTEventListener;
import java.awt.event.HierarchyEvent;

import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class OptionPaneTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final AWTEventListener hierarchyListener = new AWTEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
                final HierarchyEvent he = (HierarchyEvent) event;
                if (HierarchyEvent.HIERARCHY_CHANGED == he.getID() && he.getComponent() instanceof JOptionPane) {
                    final JDialog dlg = (JDialog) SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(he.getChangedParent());
                    if (dlg != null && !dlg.isUndecorated()) {
                        dlg.setUndecorated(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(hierarchyListener, AWTEvent.HIERARCHY_EVENT_MASK);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Border!!!");
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().removeAWTEventListener(hierarchyListener);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "With Border!!!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @SergiyMedvynskyy.  It works but the message box is not draggable. Can you please help me on that.

Comment: @Affi Take a look [here](https://github.com/develnext/develnext/blob/master/src/main/java/org/develnext/swing/ComponentMover.java). Simply copy the class `ComponentMover` in your code and add the line `new ComponentMover(RootPaneContainer.class, he.getComponent());` after `dlg.setUndecorated(true);` And you can drag your dialog without a title bar.