# Set Java Swing Input Dialog Always on top

Tags: java, swing, dialog

If I need to make my `JOptionPane` always on the top of everything, this is the way I can do it:

```
JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane();
JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog("My Dialog");
dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

But what about the input dialog of `JOptionPane`?
Can we do similar thing to make sure the below input dialog appear on top?

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"My Input");
```

Please note my application is not a GUI one, so I cannot set the parent window.

Comment: `JOptionPane` at it's core is just another `JComponent`, it just provides some helper methods which creates and manages the dialog for you, so, yes, you can do it, but you will have to create the dialog yourself, conceptually, something like [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17100587/setundecoratedtrue-to-a-jdialog-created-from-an-instance-of-joptionpane/17100642#17100642)

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33825679/decorating-joptionpane-showmessagedialog-like-make-borderless/33870451#33870451) is an example, how to do what you want, without to modify each call of JOptionPane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the solution by digging down the `JOptionPane` class itself.

`JOptionPane` has a method called `setWantsInput()` which we need to set `true`, to make it a input dialog.

Here is a working code:

```
JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane("body of the dialog");
optionPane.setWantsInput(true); //this is what I added
JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog("Title Of the Dialog");
dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
dialog.setVisible(true);
dialog.dispose();
System.out.println(optionPane.getInputValue());
```

Comment: how to do this for input dialog ?